# Prevent didLoad of viewcontroller in Container untill required

Tags: ios, ipad, containers

There are 10 containers(C1..C10) inside a viewcontroller (V0) all the containers are linked with 10 different view controllers(V1..V10),

Now the problem is When ever I navigate to V0 the lifecycle methods of all the viewcontrollers are called i.eViewdidload, viewwill appear are called for all the 11 controllers at the same time.

Basically the idea was the screen is divided into 2 parts with 10 buttons on left panel and depending upon the button selected the view controllers will be displayed at the right side.

So now due to load of all the 10 view controllers I am facing Performance issue :(

Any help or guide towards the solution will be really appreaciated.

Comment: What is triggering the instantiation of the 10 view controllers if they aren't currently presented?

Comment: They are added in the container and those containers are embeded from storyboard

Comment: In which case you are probably better defining the views in the storyboard and giving them identifiers but do not embed them in any active view.  You can then instantiate them using the `instantiateViewController` method of `UIStoryboard` - you can then add the view (and remove the active view) on the right